# Unity's 'Ambient' Occlusion occludes everything. How to do it better?

Tags: unity, rendering, ambient-occlusion

I'm experimenting with custom AO solutions for Unity. While looking at the source for their built-in SSAO effect, I noticed the shader is doing this:

```
half ao = tex2D (_SSAO, i.uv[1]).r;
ao = pow (ao, _Params.w);
c.rgb *= ao;
```

So basically it's darkening the whole image as a post-process where the AO term is <1, specular and diffuse components included. I'd like my version to only attenuate the ambient component while leaving the direct lighting untouched.

So how to go about this? One option would be to go to the full on deferred renderer (not legacy light pre-pass), compute the AO texture after the G-buffer pass, and incorporate it into a custom shader to do the final lighting pass. But are there simpler options that would work with light pre-pass or even forward rendering?